# How to redirect to login page using service.js file of React app?

Tags: api, redirect, error-handling, service, react-router-dom

I have written this code:

```
export default class AuthService {
static getTwitterOauthToken() {
   const url = `${apiUrl}/api/auth/getTwitterAuthToken?oauthCallback=${process.env.REACT_APP_TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL}`;
    return axios.get(url).then((response) => response.data.token).catch(function (error) {
          if(error.response.status===401){
              //redirect to login page
          }
      });
   }
}
```

Now, I have this auth service class for my functions. These functions are being called in my component. I need to catch errors in the API calls and if the calls return an error, I want to redirect my page to the login.

I don't know how to use react-router dom in service.js as it keeps showing errors. Please tell me how to redirect to the login page through the service.js file?

Comment: What are the errors? What version of `react-router-dom` is installed?  Where is this `getTwitterOauthToken` function used?

Comment: I want to catch the 401 error. `react-router-dom` version is 5.2.0. This function is used on my component page. Basically, I want to catch the 401 error for all the API calls and render them back to the login page if the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You have basically two valid options.

1. Pass the `history` object to the utility function to be used.

   Take a passed `history` object in the `getTwitterOauthToken` function.

   ```
   export default class AuthService {
     static getTwitterOauthToken(history) { // <-- history argument
       const url = " ..... ";

       return axios.get(url)
         .then((response) => response.data.token)
         .catch(function (error) {
           if (error.response.status === 401) {
             // redirect to login page
             history.replace("/login"); // <-- redirect
           }
         });
     }
   }
   ```

   The caller must pass the `history` object.

   ```
   const history = useHistory();

   ...

   const token = await AuthService.getTwitterOauthToken(history);
   ```
2. Create a global `history` object that is importable.

   Create a custom history object matching the type of router used, i.e. `createBrowserHistory` for a `BrowserRouter`, `createHashHistory` for a `HashRouter`, etc.

   ```
   import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
   const history = createBrowserHistory();
   export default history;
   ```

   Use the low-level `Router` instead of the high-level routers, and import the custom history object.

   ```
   import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
   import history from '../path/to/history';

   ...

   <Router history={history}>
     <App />
   </Router>
   ```

   Import the custom history object into the `AuthService` file and use.

   ```
   import history from '../path/to/history'; // <-- global history imported

   export default class AuthService {
     static getTwitterOauthToken() {
       const url = " ..... ";

       return axios.get(url)
         .then((response) => response.data.token)
         .catch(function (error) {
           if (error.response.status === 401) {
             // redirect to login page
             history.replace("/login"); // <-- redirect
           }
         });
     }
   }
   ```